# Types of arguments in method overriding

Tags: java

Can I change type of arguments while method overriding? If I do so, whether it'll be method overriding or overloading?

Comment: No, you can't. But you can narrow the return type.

Comment: It will be overloading if you change parameter types.

Comment: I haven't verified this but it should be allowable to change the type parameters of generics because of type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, except for one special case. A method can be overridden by using its erased signature, as in the following example:

```
class Example {
    void m1(List<Double> arg0) {}
    <T> void m2(T arg0) {}
}
class ErasedExample extends Example {
    // erasure of m1
    @Override
    void m1(List arg0) {}
    // erasure of m2
    @Override
    void m2(Object arg0) {}
}
```

This is noted in [§8.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> The signature of a method `m1` is a *subsignature* of the signature of a method `m2` if either:
>
> - `m2` has the same signature as `m1`, or
> - the signature of `m1` is the same as the erasure (§4.6) of the signature of `m2`.
>
> Two method signatures `m1` and `m2` are *override-equivalent* iff either `m1` is a subsignature of `m2` or `m2` is a subsignature of `m1`.

([§8.4.8.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1) is also relevant.)

So in other words, a method can override another method if either 1) the methods have the same signature *or* 2) the subtype method has the erased signature of the supertype method.